# Vue component cannot print data

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I'm just starting Vue 2. Basically, I just want to print props that I sent to component. I call the child component like this

```
`<modal 
  :open="showModal"
  :close="closeModal"
  :component="component" 
  :data="temp" 
  v-on:childHandler="test">
 </modal>`
```

And here is my component

```
Vue.component('Modal', 
{
  template: '#modal-template',props: ['open','close', 'component', 'data'],
  mounted: function () {
      console.log(this.data)
  },
 methods: {
  testing: function(){
   alert('clicked')
   this.$emit('childHandler','hehe')
  }
 }
});
```

Even though I can see that props exist within the component via Vue Devtools, I can not print it with console.log . Help please :)

Comment: maybe temp is not defined... are you trying to see the value of `this.data`

Comment: @samayo Yes I want to see the value of `this.data`. When checked it again, component Modal mounted after page loaded and at that time `this.data` was empty until I clicked on button to show modal and defined `this.data`.